# Aggregating DataFrame string columns expected to be the same

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am calling [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) on a dataframe with various numeric and string columns. For string columns, I want the result of the aggregation to be (a) the value of an arbitrary row *if* every row has that same string value or (b) an error otherwise.

I could write a custom aggregation function to do this, but is there a canonical way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can test numbers and add some aggregate function like `sum` and then if same strings column get first else raise error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['s','s3'], 'b':[5,6]})

def f(x):
    if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number):
        return x.sum()
    else:
        if x.eq(x.iat[0]).all():
            return x.iat[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError('not same strings values')
    
s = df.agg(f)
```